# A league game with 8 teams and 10 match between every pair.

Tags: combinatorics

In a league of $8$ teams, each team played every other $10$ times. The number of wins of the $8$ teams formed an arithmetic sequence. Find the least possible number of games won by the champion.
All I can think about that there will be $280$ matches.
Hence there will $280$ total wins.
If the sequence of winning is $$a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\ldots,a+7d\;,$$
then I will get $2a+7d=70$.
I can not get past that.
Please help.

Comment: Is $d=0$ allowed? If not, try $d=1$ and find $a$.  Does that work? If not, then try $d=2$ ...

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I have to find  a+7d

Comment: Note:  I assume the problem wants $d>0$, though as written the constant sequence $\{35\}$ works.

Comment: Answer is given 42 .

Answer (score 1):

You have $2a+7d=70$ and the champion scored $a+7d=70-a$.  To get the minimum champion score, you want $a$ as large as possible and $d$ as small as possible.  Since the other two terms in the equation are multiples of $7$, so must $a$ be.  By similar reasoning $d$ must be even.  If $a=35, d=0$ we have a solution if there is a tiebreak and somebody is declared champion.  If having everybody have the same score does not result in a champion, we would have $d=2, a=28$ and the champion would have $42$ wins.

Answer (score 0):

If every team plays exactly 1 match with every other team exactly once then Total Matches =8∗72=28=8∗72=28

i.e Total matches if every team plays 10 matches with every other team = 28*10 = 280

Total Wins = 280

For them to be in arithmetic progression of 8 terms, Mean = median =280/8=35=280/8=35

For mean/median of 8 terms in Arithmetic progression to be 35, the terms can NOT be consecutive so they must for an Arithmetic progression of even terms with median 35

i.e. Numbers of wins will be {28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).